# Importing Stylesheets with Variables

Tags: stylesheet, sass

I'm using `.scss` files in my Rails application and previous I was using:

```
@import "bootswatch/superhero/variables";
@import "bootswatch/superhero/bootswatch";
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
$theme: 'superhero';
@import "bootswatch/#{$theme}/variables";
@import "bootswatch/#{$theme}/bootswatch";
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the variable isn't being embedded. How can I go about doing this to avoid having to change my `application.css.scss` too many times when I want to change themes?

**Other Attempts Without Success**

```
@import "bootswatch/" + $theme + "/variables";

$theme_variables: "/bootswatch/#{$theme}/variables";
@import $theme_variables;
```

Comment: how about @import "bootswatch/" + $theme + "/variables";?

Comment: Also no good, darn. That's a good guess! `Invalid CSS after "... "bootswatch/" ": expected selector or at-rule, was "+ $theme + "/va..."`

Comment: Concerning the entire theme idea: have you considered making each theme just some variables and/or mixins and (as much as possible) using those in theme-indepent code?

Comment: I'm using the `bootswatch-rails` gem. They've already added all of the themes and whatnot, and probably are using mixins as much as possible. I was just hoping for an easier way to change themes (Not like the current way is difficult!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can't:

> Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain restrictions. It’s not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports."

see http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

This is probably because it tries to minimize recompilation between imports by calculating dependencies - which I imagine becomes very hard with dynamic imports.

I'd suggest having a main file per theme and importing that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm sorry I didn't see that earlier when I was browsing in there.